# Converting NSString to NSDate with date and time being received as different string

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I know this have been asked a lot but I am still having the problem in this conversion even after extensive search on the net. Can some one point me to my mistake in following code?

```
NSString *eventDttm = [[NSString alloc] init];
eventDttm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",myEvent.startDate,myEvent.timeFrom];
NSLog(@"eventDttm: %@",eventDttm);

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM a"];

//conversion of NSString to NSDate

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:eventDttm];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"%@",dateFromString);
```

I am getting date and time separately in string as following:

```
myEvent.startDate= 2011-11-22
myEvent.timeFrom= 08:00 PM
```

but dateFromString is always null

Comment: a side note: you don't have to initialize variables before assigning values to them.

Comment: thanks for the advice Eimants... Actually it was a result of trying of  multiple things. Sometimes I end up trying lots of illogical things when things are not working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix Months and minutes (MM & mm)

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
```